# What does sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' command mean in unix?

Tags: sed

I was going through a Unix shell script where I came across this command:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

Could someone explain this?

Comment: The reason you are getting downvotes may be: *This question does not show any research effort*.

Answer (score 12):

The command

```
sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

would act like a filter that only allowed digits to pass through.

So would

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

But due to the `g` at the end, the `*` is not needed (more at the end about this).

The regular expression `[^0-9]` means "any character that is not a digit", and the `sed` command `s/[^0-9]//g` means "replace any non-digit character with nothing, then repeat for as many times as possible on every line of input (i.e. not just the first non-digit on each line)".

Example:

```
$ echo '1-2 1-2? Is this mic on? Hello world! It is 2018!' | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
12122018
```

It is the same as the command

```
tr -dc '0-9\n'
```

which also deletes non-digit in its input (and leaves newlines alone too).

---

The difference between `[^0-9]` and `[^0-9]*` is that the former matches exactly one non-digit character while the latter matches zero or more non-digit characters.  If you want to *delete non-digits*, you don't want to match empty strings (the "zero" in "zero or more" above), so it makes more sense to match with `[^0-9]` than it does to match with `[^0-9]*`.

The `g` flag at the end of the `sed` command means "globally", i.e. everywhere on the line, not just the first match.  Removing this, you will notice that

```
$ echo '123 testing' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//'
123 testing
```

matches the empty space in front of `1`, and replaces nothing.  A more visual example of this:

```
$ echo '123 testing' | sed 's/[^0-9]*/(&)/'
()123 testing
```

... and with `g` at the end:

```
$ echo '123 testing' | sed 's/[^0-9]*/(&)/g'
()1()2()3( testing)
```

And then we have

```
$ echo '123 testing' | sed 's/[^0-9]//'
123testing
```

which matches and replaces the space, which is a non-digit. A more visual example of that:

```
$ echo '123 testing' | sed 's/[^0-9]/(&)/'
123( )testing
```

... and with `g` at the end:

```
$ echo '123 testing' | sed 's/[^0-9]/(&)/g'
123( )(t)(e)(s)(t)(i)(n)(g)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'` means deleting the non-digit characters.

**Example**

```
echo alsal34las | sed sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

will get `34`

If you want to know more about this, I suggest you take a look of [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Answer (score 1):

**Direct answer -** It searches for every occurrences of numeric in alphanumeric text and removes them.

**Explanation -**

```
 sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' filename
```

consists of following components.

1. `s/search_pattern/new_pattern/options` -    substitute(search and replace)
2. `[]`  -   regular expression.
3. `*`   -   wildcard for 0 or more occurrence.
4. `g`   -   global (an option - replaces every occurrences in that line)

Lets understand each component

**1. sed 's/search_pattern/new_pattern/options' filename**

sed 's/akshat/saxena/' file.txt

This searches every line for pattern 'akshat' and replaces only its first occurrence with 'saxena' in file having name file.txt

Here, we can give options like g(global), i(ignore case)

```
 (i) g(global)
         Discussed in point 4.

 (ii)  i - searches ignoring case (case- insensitive search)
  
   sed ' s/life/love/i' file.txt

  Replace life/Life/lIfe/liFe/life/lifE (and many more) with love
```

**2. Regular expression using []**

In regular expression, different combination or range of values can be searched.

```
 sed 's/[Li][Ii][Ff][Ee]/love/g' file
```

means pattern has L or l, followed by I or i, followed by F or f, followed by E or e.
Thus, it becomes case-insensitive search.

If a range is required dash(-) is used.
[a-z] means small a to z i.e. all alphabetic characters.
[0-9] means 0 to 9 i.e. all numeric characters.

So in given code, it refers to searching all numeric characters.

**3. `*`**

In its place any character may be present.
Thus, in given code any character can follow the regular expression [0-9]

**4. g (global)**

```
   replace all occurrence in that line.
    
       Inorder to replace first occurence in particular line use
```

sed 'n s/akshat/$$/' file

```
       where n is the line number.
```

Above code replaces pattern 'akshat' with $$ in nth line.

Answer (score 0):

@Purushottam Kumar,

```
S = search
g = Global
[^0-9]* = Searching only for the numbers starting with 0-9 in the whole document.
//g = To remove all other content other than numeric.
```

To read more below link may help you.

[GNU Sed Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Comment: `s` is usually interpreted as **s**ubstitute

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g
```

`sed` is the "stream editor", for putting at the end of a pipe (`|`), redirection (e.g. `<<<`, as in `sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' <<< 'yourstring123'`, or using directly on a file (i.e. `sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' /your/filename`).

The `s` command in sed refers to "substitute," to replace characters:

```
$ sed 's/pattern/replacment/' <<< 'pattern123pattern'
replacement123pattern
```

The `g` modifier at the end means "global," to replace throughout the line:

```
$ sed 's/pattern/replacement/g' <<< 'pattern123pattern'
replacement123replacement
```

`[^0-9]*` is a *regular expression*, which is where the magic happens for this command.

```
[: begin matching
 ^: NOT these characters:
  0-9: 0 through 9
]: end match
*: match 0 or more occurances
```

e.g., `[^0-9]*` will match anything that is not a number in the range 0 to 9:

`sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'`: replace all non-number characters with a blank string ('').

```
$ sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' <<< 'pattern123pattern'
123
$ sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' <<< '123qwertyui456opasdfghjklzxcvbnm789,./;[]=`~012+:"{}<>?345'
123456789012345
```

See man `sed(1)` and `regex(7)` for more information.